# Table Traversing with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-traversing

I have a cart page where the quantity is not the correct quantity as the products are sold in bulk (1, 10, 100 items).

What I am trying to achieve is getting the number of items in the pack, multiply by the quantity and display the total number of items.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leandroiwai/eetyr6ae/2/) and the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$( ".variant_title" ).each(function() {
  var str = $(this).text();
  var qty = $(this).nextUntil('input[id^=updates_]').val();
  console.log(qty);
  if ( str.indexOf('jackets') > -1 ) {
      unities = str.slice(18,21);
      if (unities === '100' || unities === '10 ') {

        console.log(unities);
        totalUnities = unities * qty;
        console.log(totalUnities); 
        $(this).append('<br />' + totalUnities + ' Unities');
      }
  } else {
      unities = str.slice(18,19);
      if (unities === '1') {
        console.log(unities);
        totalUnities = unities * qty;
        $(this).append('<br />' + totalUnities + ' Unity');
      }
  }
});
});
```

Table example

[image]

My problem now is traversing the DOM and getting the value of the input field next to the description and multiplying.

Does anyone know where am I making a mistake here?

Thanks

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question. If the third party link dies, or becomes unavailable your question becomes un-answerable.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var str = $(this).text();
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');  
  var qty = $(tr).find('input').val();
  console.log(qty);
```

Yo need to get your parent element (tr here) and find the input to get your quantity. hope this help

Answer (score 0):

**nextUntil(-selector-)** method selects all prior elements to -selector-
use this approach to get quantity:

```
var str = $(this).text();
var qty = $(this).parents('.item').next('td.qty').find("input[id^='updates_']").val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eetyr6ae/3/

Comment: I did, but I don't have enough points to be able to vote but it says once I do have enough points, the vote will be computed. Thanks RomanPerekhrest.